# Filename in variable used for formulas and copying

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a wildcard filename as a variable so I can use it to copy and do some formulas. And then I want to flatten all the formulas.

It looks like this:

This first part works (first thing opens wildcard file from a cell formula and second assigns only filename without path to variable Prod - hovering over variable prod gives exactly what it should)

```
Dim wbProd As Workbook
Windows("SB.xlsm").Activate
Set wbProd = Workbooks.Open(FileNAME:=Sheets("refs").Range("B48").Value)
Dim Prod As String
Windows("SB.xlsm").Activate
Prod = Worksheets("refs").Range("B49").Value

Windows("Weekly.xlsx").Activate
With Workbooks(" & Prod & ").Sheets("Report 1")
.Range("A2:BG10", .Range("A2:BG10").End(xlDown)).Copy Workbooks("WeeklyData X.xlsx").ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
End With

Windows("WeeklyData X.xlsx").Activate
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report 1")
ws.UsedRange.Value = ws.UsedRange.Value
```

I am getting an error with this first part of copying: With Workbooks(" & Prod & ").Sheets("Report 1"). When I use this copying method without using filename in a variable it works and also when I use variable filename to do Vlookups it works. I dont know what would be the reason not to work here. 
Also if you have better way to flatten all the formulas and preseve formats (coz of dates) it would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix would be to create a Workbook variable (`Dim myWB as Workbook`),

Then do `Set myWB = Workbooks(Prod)`.  Then just do `With myWB.Sheets("Sheet1")`.

The issue is that Excel needs quotes in the sheet name, and so your book is literally being understood as being titled `& Prod &`. So, to keep your current idea, you need to just add an additional quote to each quote: `With Workbooks("" & Prod & "").Sheets("Report 1")`.

Personally I recommend setting up a workbook variable, but either works!

Edit: 
@drLecter - Very welcome!  You'll also run into the "double quotes" issue when trying to set up formulas that have quotes in them.  IE The worksheet formula `=Vlookup("myText",A1:D1,2,False)` would, in VBA, become

`Cells(1,1).Formula = "=Vlookup(""myText"",A1:D1,2,False)"`.

As you can see, if I didn't use double quotes, VBA would stop reading the formula at

`Cells(1,1).Formula = "=Vlookup(`

Comment: That is it. Damn, I was fiddling with it for hours. Thank you mate. And thanks for the schooling on a side. Always appreciated.

Comment: @drLecter - Very welcome! I updated my answer with a little more info, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dir()` !

[Microsoft Documentation link - dir() function](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8&q=dir%20function%20excel%20vba&oq=dir%20function%20excel%20vba&aqs=chrome.0.0l5.2775j0j7)

-Returns a string representing the name of a file, directory, or folder that matches a specified pattern or file attribute, or the volume label of a drive.

just adapt something like this::

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
   file = Dir("c:\testfolder\")
   While (file <> "")
      If InStr(file, "test") > 0 Then
         MsgBox "found " & file
         Exit Sub
      End If
     file = Dir
  Wend
End Sub
```